# What's the meaning of "around" in these sentences?

Tags: word-meaning

> "What's working around communication? What's not?"
>
> "What's working for you around influence? What's not?"

Please tell me the meaning of these sentences. I have problem with the word "around" and so I can't understand the meaning of these sentences.

These questions were found in a [leadership coaching blog](https://www.thecoachingtoolscompany.com/leadership-coaching-more-important-than-ever-11-focus-areas-plus-questions-jennifer-britton/):

> **Coaching Questions to Explore with Clients:**
>
> 1. What's working ***around*** communication? What's not?
> 2. Thinking about your team, what are their preferences around communication? What are your preferences around communication?
> 3. What are the strengths you bring to communication?
> 4. What are your communication blindspots?
> 5. What difficult conversations need to happen?
>
> **Coaching Questions to Explore with Clients:**
>
> 1. What does influence mean for you?
> 2. What does influence look like?
> 3. Where is influence most important to you in your role/team/department?
> 4. What's working for you ***around*** influence? What's not?